# Fingerprint Scanner - TTL (GT-511C3) message issue

Tags: message, fingerprint, ttl

I am having difficulty setting up my fingerprint Scanner - TTL (GT-511C3). I have bought it from http://www.w11stop.com/manufacturer-sparkfun  I'm using the library from https://github.com/sparkfu/Fingerprint_Scanner-TTL/tree/master/FPS_GT511C3 and none of the example sketches work.

I have a message printing to the serial before the fps.open() command and a message printing afterwards, but I only ever see the first message.  Does this mean the `arduino` is stuck trying to open the scanner?

Comment: Please provide the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

try and get 'Demo software' from this [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11792)

and see if the software can access the sensor.